# Field extension $\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt2)$; why is adding $\sqrt2$ not enough?

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

This an extract from Visual Group theory book section 10.5.1 page-234 ,which says that:

[image]

What I can't understand from this extract is for what purpose do we need to add other elements except $\sqrt{2}$ only?

Comment: @lhf: fixed, I hope

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The purpose is to have a *field*, a "number system capable of arithmetic", meaning a set of numbers closed under the arithmetic operations $+,-,\times,\div$.

Edited to address some comments: I think the writer's phrasing is legitimately confusing. The first sentence makes it sound like the writer's only goal is to solve $x^2-2=0$; if that were the only goal, then considering the entire field $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)$ wouldn't be necessary. But a second priority (and, I submit, the more important priority) is to have "a number system capable of arithmetic, a field". Once we recognize that as a goal, we agree that "It is not enough to add the single number $\sqrt2$". But the writer should have rearranged the order of these sentences to make this clearer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,but how does creating a number system help me   with solving equation $x^2$-2=0.Please explain,I'm confused.

Comment: @WantTobeAbstract In the (economical) extension there is a solution for this equation: $\sqrt2$. The extension is 'nice' in the sense that Greg describes. Would you prefer $\mathbb Q\cup\{\sqrt2\}$ here? I would not.

Comment: @Greg Martin what I can't understand is probably the line mentioned in the paragraph mentioned in question from the book saying 'how far I'm forced to reach to solve $x^2$-2=0'

Comment: @drhab please can you be more clear with your explanation as I still can't understand.

Comment: @WantTobeAbstract "..for what purpose do we need to add other elements except $\sqrt2$.." Well just to maintain the possibility to add, multiply etc. without coming into trouble. Just as Greg answers. In e.g. $\mathbb Q\cup\{\sqrt2\}$ there is no nice addition: $1+\sqrt2=??$.

Comment: @drhab I agree with your explanation.thanks.